# Probability of selecting the same element

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation, probability

Let's say I have a list of 30,000 names. I want to select 4 times from a set of 8 possible fruits. However, I want the probability of any name selecting ANY fruit twice to be 20%. How would I go about this in code.

**As an example:**
List of 30,000 names
Fruits:

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Grape
- Kiwi
- Pineapple
- Watermelon
- Dragonfruit

I want the probability of John selecting Apple Apple Banana Orange OR Apple Banana Orange Banana OR Dragonfruit Watermelon Grape Grape OR Grape Grape Grape Kiwi   to be EXACTLY 20%.

In other words, I want 80% of the list of names to have NO matching fruits selected and 20% to have 1 pair of matching fruits.

Comment: How does 30000 correspond to 8?

Comment: It doesn't just 30,000 names selecting from a pool of 8 fruits

Comment: Or to make it easier 30,000 ANYTHING selecting 4 times from a pool of 8 ANYTHING

Comment: These are bizarre requirements. Is there any reason you would like these specific probabilities and sizes?

Comment: just an example to make it clear

Comment: If you want EXACTLY 20%, then you need to randomly select 6000 names from the list, randomly choose 3 fruits, and then choose the fourth fruit from one of the first 3. The other 24000 names must be forced to choose 4 unique fruits. Choosing exactly 6000 out of 30000 and exactly 4 out of 8 can be done with a Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) easily here.

For each person, decide if they are in the 20% or the 80%. If you want exactly 20% of your sample, randomly choose the 6000 of your population at the start.

If they're in the 20%, repeatedly choose for them 4 fruits from your set of 8, until they contain a single repeated fruit.

If they're in the 80%, repeatedly choose for them 4 fruits from your set of 8, until they don't contain a repeat.

Here's some python code that generates 30 samples (rather than 30000 for demonstration purposes) of which 20% contain a duplicated fruit:

```
import random

N = 30

fruits = 'Apple Banana Orange Grape Kiwi Pineapple Watermelon Dragonfruit'.split()

def sample(repeats):
    while True:
        s = [random.choice(fruits) for _ in range(4)]
        if len(set(s)) == 4 - repeats:
            return s


population = list(range(N))
twenty_percenters = set(random.sample(population, N // 5))

for p in population:
    in20 = p in twenty_percenters
    print(p, '*' * in20, sample(in20))
```